# Cross compiling fontconfig for iOS

Tags: ios, cross-compiling, fontconfig

How to cross compiling for fontconfig for iOS.
http://freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/release

I try this:

```
./configure
CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang"
CFLAGS="-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -arch armv7"
--sysconfdir=/Users/bluefish625/Desktop/fontconfig/sysconfdir/
--prefix=/Users/bluefish625/Desktop/fontconfig/prefix/
--mandir=/Users/bluefish625/Desktop/fontconfig/mandir
--disable-shared
--host=armv7-apple-darwin
--with-freetype-config=$PREFIX/bin/freetype-config
```

The error info is:

```
configure: error: in `/Users/bluefish625/Downloads/fontconfig-2.9.0':
configure: error: The pkg-config script could not be found or is too old.
Make sure it is in your PATH or set the PKG_CONFIG environment variable to the full path to pkg-config.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBXML2_CFLAGS
and LIBXML2_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

To get pkg-config, see <http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org/>.
See `config.log' for more details
```

And,I don't know what this `--with-freetype-config` means?
can somebody help me? thanks.

Comment: Generally it means you don't have the dependencies required to compile fontconfig, or your path is messed up. If you use homebrew and install fontconfig via brew it should install all the dependencies.

Comment: Can you give me a link about homebrew? thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

Comment: @Magicfish do you find a solution to compile fontconfig for an iOS target?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
export IOS_PLATFORMDIR="/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform"
export IOS_SYSROOT="$IOS_PLATFORMDIR/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk"
export IOS_GCC="$IOS_PLATFORMDIR/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2"
export IOS_CFLAGS="-march=armv6 -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -mfpu=vfp"

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin10 --disable-docs --enable-shared=no \
           --with-expat="/Users/meox/PODOFO/expat" \
           --with-expat-includes="/Users/meox/PODOFO/expat/include" \
           --with-expat-lib="/Users/meox/PODOFO/expat" \
CC="$IOS_GCC" LD="$IOS_GCC" \
CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -isysroot $IOS_SYSROOT -O3 $IOS_CFLAGS" \
LDFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -isysroot $IOS_SYSROOT $IOS_CFLAGS
-L/Users/meox/PODOFO/freetype2 -L/Users/meox/PODOFO/expat
-L/Users/meox/PODOFO/zlib -L/Users/meox/PODOFO/libiconv
-L/Users/meox/PODOFO/bzip2" \
CPPFLAGS="-I/Users/meox/PODOFO/freetype2/include
-I/Users/meox/PODOFO/zlib/include -I/Users/meox/PODOFO/expat/include"
```

You have to set the right paths.